# Is NUnit's ExpectedExceptionAttribute only way to test if something raises an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, nunit

I'm completely new at C# and NUnit.

In Boost.Test there is a family of `BOOST_*_THROW` macros. In Python's test module there is `TestCase.assertRaises` method.

As far as I understand it, in C# with NUnit (2.4.8) the only method of doing exception test is to use `ExpectedExceptionAttribute`.

Why should I prefer `ExpectedExceptionAttribute` over - let's say - Boost.Test's approach? What reasoning can stand behind this design decision? Why is that better in case of C# and NUnit?

Finally, if I decide to use `ExpectedExceptionAttribute`, how can I do some additional tests after exception was raised and catched? Let's say that I want to test requirement saying that object has to be valid after some setter raised `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`. How would you fix following code to compile and work as expected?

```
[Test]
public void TestSetterException()
{
    Sth.SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();

    // Following statement won't compile.
    Assert.Raises( "System.IndexOutOfRangeException",
                   obj.SetValueAt( -1, "foo" ) );

    Assert.IsTrue( obj.IsValid() );
}
```

---

Edit: Thanks for your answers. Today, I've found an *It's the Tests* [blog entry](http://nunit.com/blogs/?p=63) where all three methods described by you are mentioned (and one more minor variation). It's shame that I couldn't find it before :-(.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm surprised I haven't seen this pattern mentioned yet. David Arno's is very similar, but I prefer the simplicity of this:

```
try
{
    obj.SetValueAt(-1, "foo");
    Assert.Fail("Expected exception");
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
    // Expected
}
Assert.IsTrue(obj.IsValid());
```

Comment: Won't Assert.Fail("...") dump you out of the test with an AssertionFailedException?

Comment: Yes. However, if the call to SetValueAt throws an exception (which we want to happen), control immediately moves to the catch-block and bypasses Assert.Fail, thus passing the test. If SetValueAt does not throw an exception, then behavior is not as excepted and the test should fail.

Comment: That is neater than my way of doing it. I'll use your approach in future :)

Answer (score 10):

If you can use NUnit 2.5 there's some nice [helpers](http://nunit.com/blogs/?p=63) there.

```
Assert.That( delegate { ... }, Throws.Exception<ArgumentException>())
```

Comment: +1.  I prefer using this style as there's less ceremony required to write the test, especially if you need to keep a reference for checking messages etc.  You can also use var exception = Assert.Throws<MyExceptionType>(() => myInstance.DoSomethingInvalid());

Answer (score 4):

The MbUnit syntax is

```
Assert.Throws<IndexOutOfRangeException>(delegate {
    int[] nums = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
    nums[3] = 3;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've always adopted the following approach:

```
bool success = true;
try {
    obj.SetValueAt(-1, "foo");
} catch () {
    success = false;
}

assert.IsFalse(success);

...
```

Comment: Personally I'd catch a specific exception, but that'll work ;-p

Comment: @Marc, valid point: it should catch the specific exception under test and let others through so that they appear as errors rather than test failures.

Answer (score 2):

Your preferred syntax:

```
Assert.Raises( "System.IndexOutOfRangeException",
               obj.SetValueAt( -1, "foo" ) );
```

woiuldn't work with C# anyway - the obj.SetValueAt would be evaluated and the result passed to Assert.Raises. If SetValue throws an exception, then you'd never get into Assert.Raises.

You could write a helper method to do it:

```
void Raises<T>(Action action) where T:Exception {
   try {
      action();
      throw new ExpectedException(typeof(T));
   catch (Exception ex) {
      if (ex.GetType() != typeof(T)) {
         throw;
      }
   }
}
```

Which allows the similar syntax of:

```
Assert.Raises<System.IndexOutOfRangeException>(() => 
  obj.SetValueAt(-1, "foo")
;
```